# A logic exercise (finite satisfiability)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am new here and this is my first post.
Had a logic exercise, thought of a solution but I am not sure.

> If the wff $(\phi_1 \wedge  \phi_2 \wedge... \wedge \phi_n)\rightarrow \phi_0$ is valid and S is a set of wffs such that any finite subset of S is satisfiable then prove that for some of the sets:
>   $$
> S\cup\{\phi_{0}\},S\cup\{\neg\phi_{1}\},\ldots,S\cup\{\neg\phi_{n}\}
> $$
>   has every finite subset satisfiable  without using the compactness or the completeness-soundness theorems.

My suggestion for a solution is that the wff is equivalent to $\neg(\phi_{1}\wedge\phi_{2}\wedge...\wedge\phi_{n})\vee\phi_{0} $ that means that, for every interpretation $M$, either i)  $\phi_0$ must be true in $M$ or ii)$(\phi_{1}\wedge\phi_{2}\wedge...\wedge\phi_{n})$ must be false in $M$ and then treat either case separately. In the first case (i) $S\cup{\phi_0}$ is finite satisfiable in the second (ii) some the other sets is since at least one $\phi_i$ must false. I believe i can work the details but is my initial thought right? Is in the right direction for the proof?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X' \subseteq S$. We want to prove that $X' \subseteq S \cup \{\phi_0\}$ or $X' \subseteq S \cup \{\neg \phi_1\}$ or ... or $X' \subseteq S \cup \{\neg \phi_n\}$ such that $X'$ is finite and satisfiable ('finite satisfiable, for short). Now we state our assumptions:

> Suppose $\vDash (\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2 \wedge ... \wedge \phi_n) \rightarrow \phi_0$ and that $X \subseteq S$ is finite satisfiable.

Now we pick up your suggestion of treating the above formula in terms of disjuntion, since **in classic logic** $\vDash_v (\phi \vee \psi)$ means $max(v(\phi),v(\psi))=1$, which is to say that

> $\vDash_v \phi$ or $\vDash_v \psi$.

The statement we want to prove is a disjuntion. Therefore, we divide the proof in two cases:

**Case 1**: $X' \subseteq S \cup \{\phi_0\}$.

> We recall that since $\vDash (\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2\wedge ... \phi_n) \rightarrow \phi_0$, then the antecedent is false or the consequent true. Let $M'$ be an interpretation such that $M'(\phi_0)=1$. Then we got our result since by our assumption $X \subseteq S$ is finite satisfiable. Now let $M''(\phi_0)=0$. We have to guarantee that the other disjunct holds whenever $M''(\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2 \wedge ... \wedge \phi_n)=0$ (see the following case).

**Case 2**: $X' \subseteq S \cup \{\neg \phi_1\}$ or $X' \subseteq S \cup \{\neg \phi_2\}$ or ... or $X' \subseteq \cup \{\neg \phi_n\}$.

> We just need to take in consideration the interpretations $M''$ above described. Since $M''(\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2 \wedge ... \wedge \phi_n)=0$, it means there exists at least one $\phi_k$ such that $M''(\phi_k)=0$. Then since our assumption that $X \subseteq S$ is finitely satisfiable, it follows that $X' \subseteq S \cup \{\neg \phi_k\}$ is finitely satisfiable.

Comment: In the previous conversation I said that I cannot figure out the difference of the meanings 'truth' and 'validity'. Are they the same or there can be a formula that is true but not valid or the opposite? A true formula is a tautology: it is true under any truth assignment. A valid formula isn't always true? What if we speak of truth and not validity? What's the problem with that?

Comment: @Harry Both concepts are a bit confusing at the start. But be careful: A *valid* formula is a tautology (not a true formula). Naturally, we can speak of truth without implying validity. I will be happy to provide a longer explanation later, if this clarification is not enough. If it is, please mark my answer as the reply for your question.

Comment: @Bentzen I am still not completely sure if I get the notions of validity and truth. You say they are different but I cannot see it,yet I hope. From Enderton, 'Introduction to logic', it reads in chapter 2.2: "The first-order analogue of the concept of a tautology is the concept of a valid formula:A wff $\phi$ is valid iff $\textrm{Ø}\models\phi$, thus $\phi$ is valid iff for every model $A$ and assignment $s:V\rightarrow |A|$, $A$ satisfies $\phi$ with $s$". And since the bounty I think I 'll leave it open for the next few days.

Comment: Actually, a tautology is a nickname for a valid formula. So, let's just talk about truth and validity. The validity of a formula $\phi$ means $\phi$ is true under every truth assignment. Is that okay for you? So, in other words, a valid formula can't be false (since there is no truth assignment that falsifies it, by definition. However, propositions can be true, without being valids (can you see this?)

Comment: In the usual terminology, "truth" is a statement about a formula and an interpretation ($\forall x \cdot x^2 \not= -1$ is true in  the real numbers but not in the complex numbers). So it doesn't make sense to say a proposition can be true but not valid (since the first assertion requires some context, but the second doesn't).

Comment: @Rob This, however, was the doubt of the questioner, which was confused about those conceopts. It's obvious a formula $\phi$ is true *under some interpretation* $M$, and this was explicit in my comment above about truth assigments in the propositional calculus.

Comment: @bof "finite satisfiable" is just a name for easier typing. $X \subseteq S$ is finite satisfiable means ' $X$ is a finite subset of $S$ such that it is satisfiable'. And as you can see, since $X\subseteq S$ is actually arbitrary, I'm proving that.the statement holds for every finite subset of $S$. I.just omitted the universal generalization of the proof.

Comment: @bof It means it's both a finite subset of $S$ and satisfiable. The details of the proof are quite alike the ones of you comment above